# What's causing my Rubymotion app to Crash?

Tags: ios, rubymotion

Since I upgraded Rubymotion to 1.17 my app has started crashing after a second or so of becoming active

There's no error message being displayed and I can't see what's wrong from the [crash log](https://gist.github.com/b02f3707105b4ab070d5) can anyone help?

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000050000008
```

Answer (score 2):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)` means that you are trying to access a memory address(`0x0000000050000008`in your case) that is invalid.  The address exist, but your program does not have access to it.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446655/exception-types-in-ios-crash-logs) question has a list of these kinds of signals and a few ways to handle them.

Are you sure this is related to the new version of Rubymotion and not a change in your code?  If so you may want to file a bug report by running `motion support` in terminal.

Comment: Thanks Josh - I addressed the issue with Rubymotion support and Laurent fixed the bug. Whatever it was that was causing it should be corrected in the next release

Comment: I just updated to 1.18 and it looks like it has been fixed! "Fixed a problem introduced in 1.16 that was causing objects returned from certain initializers to be autoreleased twice."