# What do the different exception codes in OS X / iOS Crash reports mean?

Tags: ios, macos, crash-reports

In Apple crash reports, there are two lines providing `Exception Type` and `Exception Codes` for the crash report. Does anybody know what all these codes actually mean?

There are some self-explaining ones ones, like `KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS`:

For example, this one is a **NULL Pointer dereference**:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
```

If you made an error with pointer arithmetic, you'll end up with something very similar:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00007fff50399000
```

But there are lots of these exception codes! For example, here's one I recently encountered and I have no clue what it means (the address points to a big memory-mapped file):

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: 0x000000000000000a, 0x0000000137676004
```

All I found about crash reports was [this technote](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2004/tn2123.html), but no detailed reference how to interpret exception codes.

Comment: [Unix signal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal)

Comment: This is a possible dupliate question (refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446655/exception-types-in-ios-crash-logs))

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I'm more interested in the Exception Codes, not just the signals. (in my the last example SIGBUS can mean many different things, I assume that the code `0x000000000000000a` contains more detail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list of exception codes can be found in the [xnu source](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2050.22.13/osfmk/mach/kern_return.h). 0x000000000000000a is KERN_MEM0RY_ERROR:

```
#define KERN_MEMORY_ERROR       10
    /* During a page fault, the memory object indicated
     * that the data could not be returned.  This failure
     * may be temporary; future attempts to access this
     * same data may succeed, as defined by the memory
     * object.
     */
```